# Tramp Issue in Emacs 24.4 Installed through Homebrew

Tags: macos, mac, emacs, homebrew, tramp

I recently installed Emacs 24.4 through homebrew through the command

```
brew install emacs --cocoa
```

I need to edit the files in a remote cluster with two step authentication. To do this I save the login credentials for the remote cluster through ControlMaster in ~/.ssh/config as

```
Host *
ForwardAgent yes
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
ServerAliveCountMax=30
ServerAliveInterval=5
```

However when I try to edit the remote cluster files through tramp as

```
/ssh:username@remotecluster:~/filename
```

the emacs hangs with the message *Waiting for prompts from remote shell* which shows that tramp is NOT recognizing the ssh config information.

I provided the option

`(setq tramp-verbose 500)`

in ~/.emacs and I got the following message in the tramp debug buffer which gets repeated over & over.

*Error Message:*

```
    14:19:45.324180 tramp-file-name-handler (1) # Suppress received in operation (file-exists-p
    14:19:45.324396 tramp-get-file-property (8) #  file-truename nil
    14:19:45.324550 tramp-flush-directory-property (8) # 
    14:19:45.324713 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
    14:19:45.324897 tramp-flush-connection-property (7) # [ssh username remotecluster nil nil] nil
    14:19:45.325106 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
    14:19:45.325306 tramp-get-file-property (8) # / file-truename nil
    14:19:45.325462 tramp-flush-file-property (8) # /
    14:19:45.325863 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # ~ undef
    14:19:45.326046 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
    14:19:45.326224 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-name nil
    14:19:45.326376 tramp-get-connection-property (7) # process-buffer nil
```

*Note:* Following the same procedure, I **do not** face any issue using tramp in emacs 24 in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

For further analysis, one would need to investigate the whole debug buffer. Setting tramp-verbose to 500 looks impressive, a value of 10 would suffice already :-)

You could send me the debug buffer directly per email for analysis. Or use the Tramp mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

> "Waiting for prompts from remote shell"

There are other possibilities here. Your prompt may not match `tramp-shell-prompt-pattern` Can you post the values of `tramp-shell-prompt-pattern` and `tramp-password-prompt-regexp` . I recently added Passcode to mine to use two factor auth.

```
(setq tramp-password-prompt-regexp
 (concat
  "^.*"
  (regexp-opt
   '("Passphrase" "passphrase"
     "Password" "password"
     "Passcode" "passcode) t)
  ".*:\0? *"))
```

I'm also curious if you got the Control master to work.